# Split line based on regex in Julia

Tags: regex, julia

I'm interested in splitting a line using a regular expression in Julia. My input is a corpus in Blei's LDA-C format consisting of `docId wordID : wordCNT` For example a document with five words is represented as follows:

```
186 0:1 12:1 15:2 3:1 4:1
```

I'm looking for a way to aggregate words and their counts into separate arrays, i.e. my desired output:

```
words =  [0, 12, 15, 3, 4]
counts = [1,  1,  2, 1, 1]
```

I've tried using `m = match(r"(\d+):(\d+)",line)`. However, it only finds the first pair `0:1`. I'm looking for something similar to Python's `re.compile(r'[ :]').split(line)`. How would I split a line based on regex in Julia?

Comment: Instead of split., just globally search using  `(\d+):(\d+)`, append each group result into a different array.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to use regex here; Julia's [`split`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.split) function allows using multiple characters to define where the splits should occur:

```
julia> split(line, [':',' '])
11-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "186"
 "0"
 "1"
 "12"
 "1"
 "15"
 "2"
 "3"
 "1"
 "4"
 "1"

julia> words = v[2:2:end]
5-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "0"
 "12"
 "15"
 "3"
 "4"

julia> counts = v[3:2:end]
5-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "1"
 "1"
 "2"
 "1"
 "1"
```

Answer (score 5):

I discovered the `eachmatch` method that returns an iterator over the regex matches. An alternative solution is to iterate over each match:

```
words, counts = Int64[], Int64[]
for m in eachmatch(r"(\d+):(\d+)", line)
    wd, cnt = m.captures
    push!(words,  parse(Int64, wd))
    push!(counts, parse(Int64, cnt))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Matt B**. mentions, there's no need for a Regex here as the Julia lib *split()* can use an array of chars.

However - when there *is* a need for Regex - the same split() function just works, similar to what others suggest here:

```
line = "186 0:1 12:1 15:2 3:1 4:1"
s = split(line, r":| ")
words = s[2:2:end]
counts = s[3:2:end]
```

I've recently had to do exactly that in some Unicode processing code (where the split chars - where a "combined character", thus not something that can fit in julia 'single-quotes') meaning:

```
split_chars = ["bunch","of","random","delims"]
line = "line_with_these_delims_in_the_middle"
r_split = Regex( join(split_chars, "|") )
split( line, r_split )
```